# Confused to use Present Simple Tense or Present Perfect Tense

Tags: present-tense

Today Bangladesh has won any tri nation series very firstly. The Daily Star has wrote, " Bangladesh win tri-nation series final. "

My question is, Shouldn’t it be like Bangladesh has won tri-nation series final?

I am not too good at English. Forgive me and help me to correct anything if I make any mistake here. Thanks.

Comment: It's a newspaper headline. Expect them to be terse or tense, but not the right tense.

Comment: Yes, _Bangladesh has won..._ would normally be correct. However, newspaper headlines are often written in the present tense, to emphasise that they are giving us the latest news.

Comment: They're treating *Bangladesh* as one of those funny British plurals, like "The faculty agree*.  It's a present tense.

Comment: @StoneyB You are right. I confess to misunderstanding aparente001's point. For that reason I will delete my comment with apologies. We are, however, not amused at your amusement.

Comment: @WS2 Quite. When you do it, it's quaint. When we do it it's hegemonism. Everybody loses.

Answer (score 2):

The event of Bangladesh winning the final is a past event, and a past event is usually encoded with either the past simple form or the present perfect form:

> past simple form: *Bangladesh won the final.*
>
> present perfect form: *Bangladesh has/have won the final.*

The past simple form emphasizes that the event is not immediate to the speaker, whereas the present perfect form emphasizes that, although the event itself is not immediate to the speaker, the event is being viewed as immediate to the speaker by focusing on the immediacy of the resultative impact of the event on the present time rather than focusing on the event itself that is not immediate. Therefore, the present perfect form conveys a more subjective feel to it than the past simple form.

Because news headlines should necessarily convey immediacy and an objective feel, neither the past simple nor the present perfect sounds right. The only form that can convey immediacy and an objective feel is the present simple. Hence, "Bangladesh win(s) the final."